# runs.test() works only with even numbers of n1 and n2

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio

I have a list of vectors (dados_obs) that contains "0" and "1". Head and Tails.

I have to test it's randomness. So I made a huge simulation to get the p-value and compare with my list of vectors of 0 and 1 to test if they were made up or actually random. It worked fine

I discovered it runs.test does that for me, but i have a problem. It only works when my number of 0's and 1's are evenly split with n1 = n2 = 50, with n = 100.

```
runs.test(dados_obs[[16]])
```

Gives me

```
Runs Test

data:  dados_obs[[16]]
statistic = 0.60305, runs = 54, n1 = 50, n2 = 50, n = 100, p-value = 0.5465
alternative hypothesis: nonrandomness
```

But

```
runs.test(dados_obs[[17]])
```

Gives me

```
    Runs Test

data:  dados_obs[[17]]
statistic = NaN, runs = 1, n1 = 0, n2 = 49, n = 49, p-value = NA
alternative hypothesis: nonrandomness
```

Is there a way to overcome this limitation? When n1 differs from n2 (Sum of Head differs from Sum of Tails)?

Comment: the problem is about your data. it says n1 has no valid observation n1 = 0

Comment: I suspected that, but the test runs perfectly when n1 = n2 = 50. Why it wouldn't work when it´s different?

Comment: and if I do str(dados_obs) it gives me : num [1:100] for all of them

Comment: what does summary(dados_obs[[17]]) gives ?

Comment: Min: 0.00 | 1st. Qu. : 0.00 | Median: 1.00 | Mean : 0.51 | 3rd. Qu : 1.00 | Max: 1.00
The point is, runs.test() only works when the number of Head and Tails is 50.

Comment: what is table(dados_obs[[17]]) then ?

Comment: 0 = 49 and 1 = 51

Comment: this works factor(c(rep(1,51), rep(0,49)) ) %>% tseries::runs.test()

Comment: well, i don't think so. it gives me a really tiny p-value, and the correct would be 0.5414.

Comment: that is about the sequence of observations

Comment: (runif(100, 1,2) - 1) %>% round() %>% factor() %>% tseries::runs.test()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `runs.test` from `randtests` looks like it has not been updated since 2014. Maybe try the one in `snpar`? (Also need `magrittr` for pipes.)

```
library(snpar)
library(magrittr)
```

For example:

```
> sample(c(0,1),20,replace=TRUE) %>% snpar::runs.test()

    Approximate runs rest

data:  .
Runs = 13, p-value = 0.3581
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

> sample(c(0,1),100,replace=TRUE) %>% snpar::runs.test()

    Approximate runs rest

data:  .
Runs = 43, p-value = 0.1146
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Comment: Great! So glad it helped you with your task.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had the same problem as you. Then I added the cut point that i used, in the syntax (with `randtests` package). Example with your code :

```
runs.test(dados_obs[[17]], threshold = mean(dados_obs[[17]]))
```

The cut points can be mean, mode, median, etc. We used it to specified the n1 and n2.